# Upcast from Const Reference Interface to Derived Class

Tags: c++, casting

**Edit:** Turns out what I am talking about is really a *down* cast not an up cast. So ignore where I say *up*cast.

Is upcasting from a const reference interface to a derived class valid and can it cause problems? Will I encounter problems that I am unaware of (apart from upcasting to the wrong object I'm not aware of any other issues).

```
struct IEventArgs
{

};

// Used in Win32 application
struct WinEventArgs : public IEventArgs
{
    HWND hwnd;
    LPARAM lParam;
    WPARAM wParam;
};

// Used in POSIX application
struct PosixEventArgs : public IEventArgs
{
    // ..
};

void some_event(const IEventArgs& args)
{
    // I know/expect a WinEventArgs so I will upcast it
    const WinEventArgs& wArgs = (const WinEventArgs&)args;

    char buf[255];
    sprintf(buf, "Cast ok: %d, %d\n", wArgs.lParam,  wArgs.wParam);
    printf(buf);
}

int main()
{
    WinEventArgs args; // todo: initialise
    some_event(args);
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe I can use a different design/approach to achieve the same result? Should I just use a void pointer (although that means I cant make it const which is pretty important because the object shouldn't change).

Comment: Why do you do this downcast?If args really points to a WinEventArgs object.It should behave like a WinEventArgs.You may  consider using virtual function to return these members.@Jake M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an *upcast*, it's a *downcast*, since you are going down into the hierarchy (and actually upcasts are implicit since a `WinEventArgs` *is-a* `IEventArgs`).

In any case that's legal, you are not modifying `const`-ness. You already have a `const` reference and you downcast it to a specific derived class. Why should it cause problems?

Comment: thanks for your answer. Why, well I am c-casting in C++, maybe I should be using static cast or etc.? And I'm also curious about "good practice" and if there is a better approach I am unaware of.

Comment: I think the derived wArgs may call methods that base class don't have.@Jack upcasting is always safe, downcast not.@Jake M

Comment: I suggest using static_cast instead of c-style casting.@JakeM

Comment: @YuanWen he wrote that he expects a WinEventArgs so we're assuming OP really wants a downcast

Comment: what does OP stand for?@Jack

Comment: My ears are burning :D. @YuanWen OP stands for 'Original Poster of the question', ie, me :D

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow and not a native English speaker.So I can't easily understand the abbreviation.@JakeM